# Como extrair um binário de uma string?

Tags: erlang

Tenho a seguinte **lista de decimais** em Erlang:
`"01000001" == [48, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 48]`

Preciso criar um tipo binário à partir dessa lista, logo:
`<<01000001>> == <<"A">>`

Já tentei converter com a função `list_to_binary/1`, mas ela se torna:
`<<"01000001">> == <<48, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 48>>`

Existe alguma função que faça isso? Ou como seria a melhor forma de transformar
`"01000001"` em `<<01000001>>`?

Comment: Você está pedindo duas coisas diferentes. O valor binário verdadeiro é este que você já tem. O fato de você não estar vendo não quer dizer que ele não está lá. De fato tudo é binário, e justamente por ser binário este é o verdadeiro, não tem o que fazer. 
Outra coisa é querer ver como seria o número em uma representação textual indicando onde está os bits ligados e desligado, aí você criará um texto, como este que está lendo agora, que só terá dois caracteres, um deles é o que chamados de zero (0) e outro que chamamos de um (1). Isto não é binário verdadeiro, é um texto.

Comment: @Maniero 
É, preciso ver uma forma de reformular a pergunta, na verdade o "01000001" é a string, que é o que tenho, preciso convertê-la para binário sem quer ela use os bits do caracteres 0 e 1, mas sim os caractere COMO bits.
preciso que "01000001" se tranforme em [65].

As representações que o Erlang usa são complicadas pra pegar.
"A" é "string",
<<"A">> é binário,
[65] é o mesmo que "A", porque ambos são listas de decimais.

Comment: Você ainda não entendeu porque não existe isso de binário que você está querendo converter. Ou tem um texto que representado com bits ou tem um número e não importa como ele é representado. Esse número pode até ser visualizado como letra, mas é uma questão de como apresenta, não como está na memória. Se quer que apresente de alguma forma específica, é só sobre isso que tem que falar, não como converter algo.

Comment: Eu vou tentar reescrever a pergunta, vi agora que até o título acabei apagando uma palavra, a minha pergunta é sobre tipos e não apresentação, o que tenho e o que quero se eu tentar apresentar tendo o mesmo tipo, eles vão ser diferentes.... Mas vou alterar a pergunta

Answer (score 0):

Se você precisa "transformar" `"01000001"` em `<<"01000001">>`, use a função [`list_to_binary/1`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#list_to_binary-1). Veja um exemplo:

```
erl(0)> Binary = list_to_binary("01000001").
<<"01000001">>

erl(1)> binary_to_integer(Binary, 2).       
65
```

Lembrando que `<<"01000001">>` é um açúcar sintático para `<<48, 49, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 49>>`, e isso é resolvido em tempo de compilação. Tal que se tentamos o seguinte, recebmos um erro:

```
erl(0)> Str = "01000001".
erl(1)> <<Str>>.         
** exception error: bad argument
     in function  eval_bits:eval_exp_field1/6 (eval_bits.erl, line 108)
     in call from eval_bits:eval_field/3 (eval_bits.erl, line 99)
     in call from eval_bits:expr_grp/4 (eval_bits.erl, line 68)
```